# Convert Map<String, List<Object>> to ArrayList<DataBaseModel>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, amazon-dynamodb

I am doing batchLoadItem from DynamoDB it comes back in the form:

```
Map<String, List<Object>>
```

To test it is coming back correctly i did an iteration over the returned data like this:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : individualAlarmsReturnedFromDatabase.entrySet()){
                            List<Object> value = entry.getValue();
                            System.out.println("HASH " + value);
                        }
```

and it returned this in the log:

```
HASH [com.amazonaws.models.nosql.IndividualAlarmsDatabaseModel@ab28829, com.amazonaws.models.nosql.IndividualAlarmsDatabaseModel@c36a7ae, com.amazonaws.models.nosql.IndividualAlarmsDatabaseModel@8f0994f, com.amazonaws.models.nosql.IndividualAlarmsDatabaseModel@f4188dc, com.amazonaws.models.nosql.IndividualAlarmsDatabaseModel@cc27de5]
```

This is returning correctly and as you can see the data is in the form of DataBaseModel.

I have tried all the ways I could find on stackoverflow but I don't know how to get it into an `ArrayList<DatabaseModel>` because it comes back as `Map<String, List<Object>>`

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you do something like:

`individualAlarmsReturnedFromDatabase.entrySet().stream().map(i -> new DatabaseModel(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lino's answer is great. If you can't use Java 8 streams, you can make a simple change to your existing code:

```
List<DatabaseModel> models = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
for(Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : individualAlarmsReturnedFromDatabase.entrySet()){
                        List<Object> value = entry.getValue();
                        for(Object valueObj : value)
                            models.add((DatabaseModel)valueObj);
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is this

```
List<DatabaseModel> value = (List<DatabaseModel>)entry.getValue();
// oops error
```

JIC, why error, [Read Wildcards and Subtyping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)

So we can trick the compiler by upcasting

```
List<DatabaseModel> value = (List<DatabaseModel>)((Object)entry.getValue());
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @NicholasMuir i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

**NEW ANSWER**

As you said you can't use the stream api then try the following:

```
ArrayList<DatabaseModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : map.entrySet()){
     for(Object o : entry.getValue()){
          list.add((DatabaseModel) o);
     }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Try it with `java8`-StreamAPI:

```
ArrayList<DatabaseModel> list = map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .map(o -> (DatabaseModel) o)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Above code-snippet works like the following:

1. get a Stream (foundation of `Java8-Streams`) of entries: `map.entrySet().stream()`
2. get a new stream consisting of Lists of values `.map(Map.Entry::getValue)`
3. get a new stream consisting of values `.flatMap(Collection::stream)`
4. cast the values to DatabaseModel `.map(o -> (DatabaseModel) o)`
5. Collect all the values into an ArrayList `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Comment: @NicholasMuir where do you say that? It doesn't say it in your answer. That's why I am assuming that this might work

Comment: Android studio says it when I implement your answer, it says my current minimum level is 15 and requires level 24